# Unit test channel

Tags: android, unit-testing, channel

I would like to test what was emited by my viewModel.
In viewModel I have:

```
fun setTitle(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        batchEntity ?. let{
            titleChannel.send(UiText.StringResource(R.string.edit_batch_title))
        } ?: let{
            titleChannel.send(UiText.StringResource(R.string.add_batch_title))
        }
    }
}
```

In test I have:

```
@Test
fun getTitle_AddMode() {
    runTest {
        batchAddViewModel.title.collectLatest {
            val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
            assertThat(it.asString(appContext)).isEqualTo(
                UiText.StringResource(R.string.add_batch_title).asString(appContext)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Wherever I call viewModel.setTitle test is always waiting for emmision and it always fails